# The topology endowed to a topology

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I tried to exploit the analogy between an open set and semidecidablility. As such, I declared a datatype representing outcomes of semidecision procedures:

```
data Semidecide = Halt | Iter Semidecide
```

Let the set of values covered by this datatype be denoted by $S$. For a function $f : X → S$ (represented as `f :: a -> Semidecide` in Haskell), If $f(x)$ eventually terminates with `Halt`, it means the procedure halts. Otherwise ($f(x)$ is an infinite chain of `Iter`s), it means the procedure doesn't halt. We observe that $S$ is essentially the ordinal $\omega + 1$, endowed with the order topology.

Since we're interested only in whether the procedure halts or not, we take the quotient map $q: S → \{H, I\}$, where $q(s) = H$ if and only if $s < \omega$. Now $\{H, I\}$ is the Sierpiński space.

The analogy presents a convenient way of representing open sets:

```
type Open a = a -> Semidecide
```

Denoting `Open` by $\mathsf{O}$, $\mathsf{O}$ maps a topological space to its topology. $\mathsf{O}$ also maps continuous functions, meaning that $\mathsf{O}$ is a contravariant functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$. The proof is simple. Given a continuous function $f : X → Y$, give $\mathsf{O}f : \mathsf{O}Y → \mathsf{O}X$ as $\mathsf{O}f(V) = f^{-1}[V]$.

But to think about it, $\mathsf{O}X$ is the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $\{H,I\}$, and such set has a standard topology: The compact-open topology. Does this mean $\mathsf{O}$ factors through the forgetful (covariant) functor $\mathsf{f}: \mathbf{Top} → \mathbf{Set}$?

Comment: I don't think it's true that $O f : O Y \to O X$ is continuous for arbitrary continuous $f : X \to Y$. Perhaps you want to look up exponentiable spaces.